# How to uniquely identify a control within a window?

Tags: windows, user-interface, automation

I write some automation software. I want to be able to send a message to a particular control of an application. I can find an application, but I need HWND of the control. How can I tell my software to pick that edit over here or that button over there, for example? I inspected several controls with Spy++, but I found no unique persistent properties, see images below:
[image]
[image]

The only idea I have now is to check control position, but even this is not 100% reliable, since several controls on different tabs of a tab view may have the same position!

What else could I do? How do GUI automation test suits solve this task?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, this is a useful link for .NET, and it will help in my case. But what about general case?

Comment: @HansPassant Even more, neither it, nor its modern fork are working on my application, though it is obviously written with Windows Forms.

Comment: Hmm, there is never a "general case".  UI Automation is a one-window-at-a-time battle.

Comment: @HansPassant By "general" I meant "non-.NET"

Comment: @Mikhail Did the link related to spy++ help you with it..could you please elaborate on how it did if it did actually help..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pywinauto` automation framework is able to identify control by index like `app.SomeDialog.ChildWindow(class_name='Button', ctrl_index=0).ClickInput()` which is persistent for each concrete moment if test sequence is deterministic. Also it allows more complicated matching criteria: `app.SomeDialog.ChildWindow(title='&Next', class_name='Button', parent=SomeViewContol, predicate_func=SomeFunc).ClickInput()`.

Comment: Thank you, control index is a nice idea. I am not very interested in this framework though, since I am using C++, not Python.

Comment: I took a look at pywinauto. It is so cool, I'm going to use it anyway, from C++ via Python embedding. Great thanks for the link!

Comment: Just in case... If you need 64-bit application automation, 64-bit Python compatible version is here: https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/pywinauto-64 (for 32-bit applications you still need 32-bit Python).

Comment: Glad to hear that! I'm using pywinauto for quite a long for now and it works pretty well! Unfortunately, I found it not to be very robust. It fails to do some actions spontaniously under some conditions.

Comment: Mikhail, if you have some quite often reproducible test cases for that, it would be nice to see them in the "Issues" list on github repo.

Comment: Of course, once I have time for that, I will report an issue.